# Test method delegation in Elixir

Tags: testing, elixir, delegation, ex-unit

I've got two modules:

```
defmodule Base.ModuleOne do
  def do_stuff(opts) do
    "some stuff with opts"
  end
end

defmodule Base.ModuleTwo do
  defdelegate do_stuff(opts), to: Base.ModuleOne
end
```

What is the proper way of testing delegation without copy-pasting tests for `Base.ModuleOne.do_stuff/1` function under different namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the writing of this answer, I haven't found an "official" way to test `defdelegate` either.  The only choices I can think of in your case are:

1. Just ignore testing of `Base.ModuleTwo.do_stuff(opts)`, assuming you have your bases covered in tests for `Base.ModuleOne.do_stuff(opts)`.
2. Move the bulk of (if not all of) the tests in `Base.ModuleOne.do_stuff(opts)` up to the tests for `Base.ModuleTwo.do_stuff(opts)` so your tests become directly concerned with the public interface of your module, relegating `Base.ModuleOne` to be "private" implementation detail.
3. Since [mocking would seem to be generally out of favour in Elixir](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/), consider replacing `defdelegate` with dependency injection (using a function or module; see previous link for details), which would then allow you to write tests in the following kind of way:

Module:

```
defmodule Base.ModuleTwo do
  def do_stuff(opts, dependency \\ Base.ModuleOne)
    dependency.do_stuff(opts)
  end
end
```

Test:

```
defmodule ModuleTwoTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  describe "Base.ModuleTwo.do_stuff/2" do
    defmodule TestDependency do
      def do_stuff(_opts) do
        send self(), :do_stuff
      end
    end

    test "calls do_stuff/1 on its dependency" do
      opts = %{foo: "bar"} # or whatever the `opts` should be
      Base.ModuleTwo.do_stuff(opts, TestDependency)
      assert_received :do_stuff
    end
  end
end
```